# hbase region server ip in host file

Tags: hbase

When i am connecting hbase from a remote system, i m giving the configuration the Hmaster, zookeeper ip and port number and then only the host name (where hmaster is configured). Its not connecting.

While creating the HTable object,the console hangs.

But when i specify all the ip address of regionservers in the host file, then the  same code connects.

My question is - "Do i need to specify all the IP address of region servers in the host file ? ".

Please help me understand this.

Regards,

KG

Answer (score 0):

I Think you need to provide only Zookeeper host and port to connect from hbase.
See following

```
Configuration hadoopConf = new Configuration();
hadoopConf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", zookeeperHost);
hadoopConf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", zookeeperport);
```

Comment: Along this in the code, We need to set all the host names in the system from where we are connecting.

Comment: To resolve ips you need to put the mapping in your hosts file